# How to upload picture on facebook group in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Hello My name is ryoichi.

I'm try to make iphone app.
I want make upload picture on facebook gourp.
but  I can't. I can upload picuture,comment  my wall .

I try to post facebook group, but no error.
only post comment.

this is my code

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neko.jpg"];



NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                img, @"picture", @"testcomment", @"message",
                               nil];
[img release];

NSString *test =@"/168782779916152/feed";

[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:test
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Please help me.

Comment: permissions is wrong?

permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"photo_upload,user_photos",@"user_groups", nil];

Comment: Thank you so much. dragon112 and Angel.

I use didReceiveResponse mesod.so I understand my mistake.this easy mistake. error : NSString *test =@"/168782779916152/feed"; Correct: NSString *test =@"/168782779916152/phots"; Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Dont release the img before you use it. Move the `[img release]` behind the request to send it.

Comment: thank you comment.
but still is not working.
Post comments, photos can be my wall.
but group is only comments

Answer (score 0):

@dragon112 post the correct solution but it has an error. You should never release that image since you didnt allocate/retain it! Check [memory management and ownership conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). In your example, just remove the line

```
[img release];
```

And be sure you implemented the delegate.

Comment: thank you comment. 
I'm try . 
>And be sure you implemented the delegate.
What does mean?

Comment: Well, it is not really needed but if you want to know what happened in your connection you have the delegate FBRequestDelegate (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/FBRequestDelegate/). Also, note that you have to login and request credentials before been able to to all this stuff. A nice tutorial by FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: I use didReceiveResponse mesod.so I understand my mistake.this easy mistake.
error :
NSString *test =@"/168782779916152/feed";
Correct:
NSString *test =@"/168782779916152/phots";
Thank you .